# Need a code to create a text in relation to specific index in R

Tags: r, indexing, txtextcontrol

i need to automatize a process.

I have a list of phrases, which indicate the level of correspondence to requisite.
 a .txt like this

1.1 cat is red
 1.2 blue is blue
 1.3 cggd
 1.4 dses
 2.1 blabla
 2.2 yellow is yellow
 2.3 abcded
 2.4 blablabla

what i want is obtain an automatic evaluation, by entering specific number.

for example, the work deserves 4 in the first part and two in second part.

i want to write "1.4", "2.2" and obtain a textual output, made by

"dses. yellow is yellow"

How could i do?

Thank you four your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try building your text in an array

```
yourtextarray<-matrix(c("cat is red","blue is blue","cggd","dses","blabla","yellow is yellow","abcded","blablabla"),ncol=4,nrow=2,byrow = T)
```

and then run loops over rows and columns creating your string expression

```
for(i in 1:nrow(yourtextarray)){
 for(j in 1:ncol(yourtextarray)){
  cat(paste0(i,".",j," ",yourtextarray[i,j],"\n"))}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split your data into numbers and strings, you can do string manipulation using `stringr` and `rebus` packages:

```
df <- data.frame(Text = "1.1 cat is red 1.2 blue is blue 1.3 cggd 1.4 dses 2.1 blabla 2.2 yellow is yellow 2.3 abcded 2.4 blablabla")

df <- str_match_all(df$Text, 
                    pattern = capture(DGT %R% DOT %R% DGT) %R% 
                      SPC %R%
                      capture(one_or_more(or(SPC, ALPHA)))) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

This gives you the following output:

```
#                     X1  X2                X3
# 1       1.1 cat is red  1.1       cat is red 
# 2     1.2 blue is blue  1.2     blue is blue 
# 3             1.3 cggd  1.3             cggd 
# 4             1.4 dses  1.4             dses 
# 5           2.1 blabla  2.1           blabla 
# 6 2.2 yellow is yellow  2.2 yellow is yellow 
# 7           2.3 abcded  2.3           abcded 
# 8         2.4 blablabla 2.4         blablabla
```